# MVC routing returns 404 with

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I have a problem

I'm trying to set up the folowing route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "PublicForms",
                url: "Public/Form/{*parameters}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Form", action = "Index", parameters = UrlParameter.Optional}
               );
```

but it works only when I pass more than one parameter

Example:

http://localhost:12982/Public/Form/aaa/bbb Works

```
public ActionResult Index(string parameters)
{
    // parameter comes aaa/bbb
}
```

http://localhost:12982/Public/Form/aaa doens't work.

It returns a 404

shouldn't it be ?

```
public ActionResult Index(string parameters)
{
    // parameter comes aaa
}
```

Th

Comment: it seems you have an action before the parameter. normally we use "/" sigh to separate domain items but not parameters. generally in aspx this is how we pass two parameters  "http://contoso.com/products.aspx?field1=value1 &field2=value2 " . & sign separates parameters but not "/". simplest meaning of this url is "go to contoso.com and find the product.aspx file to open it. use field1 and field2 parameters when it request them". i think this will help u

Comment: Hi @Sandaru,
I'm trying to do what is on the topic "Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern" on this article.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.140).aspx#adding_routes_to_an_mvc_application

But with doens't work with only one parameter.

Comment: Do you have any other routes?  It's impossible to debug route problems by looking at a single route, you need to look at all of them as a whole.

Comment: in that case did you try by clearing cache memory, or else start it with a separate browser and see whether its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that isn't what I wanted but works.

I can't leave the actions implicit, so I had to specify the controller and action and put an extra argument as the first parameter for when it's only one.

Now if I call the service with only one argument it doesn't return 404

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "OpenForm",
                url: "public/{controller}/{action}/{arg}/{*parameters}",
                defaults: new { categorySlug = UrlParameter.Optional ,subCategorySlug = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you try with http://localhost:12982/Public/Form/Index/aaa 
In your case you are calling an Action called "aaa" in FormController which doesn't exist.

Comment: It doesn't work too.
Actually, if I put Index in the URL it stops working even with many parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Following code was tested with:
http://localhost:50956/Public/Form/foo
so it may do something similar to what I think you are looking for. Hope it helps.

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("formPublic",
                   "Public/{*.}",
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }

                    );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```